# How to redirect post format to its current blog page number

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, post-format

I've created a wordpress theme with support for certain post formats.

When in post format status in single view **i want to redirect the user to the status post current blog page number**. Theres no link to the status post in index.php but the user can visit it by typing or from google.

```
function statusQuery($paged) {
  $query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array( 'post-format-status' )
        )
      )
    )
  );
  return $query;
}

 <?php 

 $status = statusQuery($paged); 
 while($status->have_posts()) : $status->the_post(); ?>

 <section <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <header class="entry-header">
    <h3 class="status-msg"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></h3>
  </header>
 </section>

 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

In index.php i can get the correct link with this

```
$location = get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ) . 'page/' . $paged . '/';
```

Does anybody know how to retrieve that link in single.php and the best way to redirect to it?